# Ajax call only works the 1st time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an Ajax call that only works once. You must refresh the page to use it a second time.

Here's the code:

First, this is the click event that calls the function:

```
$("#input-location").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    getWeatherWithUserInput()
        .then(function (response) {
            weatherCode = response;
            console.log(weatherCode);
            showMix(weatherCode);

        });
});
```

And here's the function that does the Ajax call.

```
function getWeatherWithUserInput() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        var location = $("#location").val().trim();
        var widget = Mixcloud.PlayerWidget(document.getElementById('my-widget-iframe'));

        var weatherCSQueryURL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q = " + 
            location + " & appid=" + WeatherAPIKey;

        $.ajax({
            url: weatherCSQueryURL,
            method: "GET"
        }).done(function (response) {
            $(".wind").html("<h1>" + response.name + "</h1>");
            resolve(response.weather[0].id);
        });
    });
};
```

Here is the Error I get when I try to use it a second time without refreshing:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentWindow' of null
    at Object.e.Mixcloud.PlayerWidget (widgetApi.js:1)
    at app.js:111
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at getWeatherWithUserInput (app.js:108)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (app.js:30)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
    at HTMLButtonElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
```

Comment: So are you saying that clicking the input-location only works once, or that the processing of the ajax response only works once?

Comment: @taplar I have to refresh to get it to work again. It looks like the error is somewhere in the promise. I forgot that I should include the error I get. I'll edit the above post.

Comment: Sounds like on the second pass 'my-widget-iframe' no longer exists

Comment: It looks like your `Mixcloud.PlayerWidget` doesn't like being reinstantiated.  It also looks like you're not actually doing anything with that widget; can you just remove that line?

Comment: @DanielBeck that was it! Thanks!